# Using Html.EnumDropDownList with nullable type defaulting to null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a nullable enum type: `Gender? gender` and it's being assigned a value of `Gender.Male` which is stored in the variable `Person.Gender`.

I have:

```
public enum Gender {
   Male = 1,
   Female = 2
}
```

So `Gender? gender = Person.Gender`

And I'm returning this in a ViewModel to my view, which is then using it in:

`Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, new { @class = "form-control" })`

On post this data is being saved. How ever, when reloading the page, the dropdown list is not defaulting to the saved value, it is displaying null / or a blank field.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: on reload are you sending to the page model the current model? with the gender value not null?

Comment: Yeah the `return View(model)` - the model is populated.

Every other field on the page is displayed correctly with values from the database.

Comment: It´s possible to show the method that are returning the View(model)?

Comment: @LeighCooper on the view does what is the `Model.Gender` value? I'm going to assume `null` if it's displaying a blank field?

Comment: @JoseRocha - sorry I cannot, and it shouldn't matter since the correct value is in the model being passed to the view.

Comment: @MaxPoshusta - strangely enough the value is not null. It's set as either Male or Female. I was able to display the text of the model.

Comment: @LeighCooper just for my curiosity, can you remove the 'form-control' class and take that 'EnumDropDownListFor' out of the form and see if it has a value as just an ugly text box? Also is there a value in dev tools if you inspect element?

Comment: @maxshuty Html.EditorFor(m => m.Gender, new { class = "form-control" }) has a value (the correct value), and a dropdown box.

Comment: @LeighCooper Did you remove the `form-control` and see if it displays?

Comment: It doesn't display, form-control is just styling.